# OSError : no Such file or directory

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code to check if a file exists in my `s3 bucket`. I give the program a directory and I am trying to upload all the files in that directory. However I have no idea why I keep running into the `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt'` error. This is my code

```
def s3_has_uptodate_file(bucket, transfer_file, source_size):

    bucket = Bucket(conn, default_bucket)
    s3_key = bucket.get_key(os.path.basename(transfer_file))
    if s3_key:
        s3_size = s3_key.size
        local_size = source_size
        s3_time = rfc822.mktime_tz(rfc822.parsedate_tz(s3_key.last_modified))
        local_time = os.path.getmtime(os.path.basename(transfer_file)) #fails here
        return s3_size == local_size and s3_time >= local_time
    return False
```

I check my stackdata and my bucket has the right bucket name, transfer file is `/Users/merlin/Desktop/test_folder/foo.txt` and source size is `141` (correct size).

I put the following lines of code into a  new file to test it out and it runs perfectly.

```
import os
transfer_file = '/Users/merlin/Desktop/test_folder/foo.txt'
local_time = os.path.getmtime(os.path.basename(transfer_file))
print local_time
```

Comment: Editing error. Fixed. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.basename(transfer_file)` will return just the file name off a path. This is a relative path from the prospective of any `os.path` methods. Unless you are running the program from the directory in which `"foo.txt"` lives in, `os.path.getmtime` will most certainly fail. You need to pass the *absolute path* to `"foo.txt"`. You probably just want to use `os.path.getmtime(transfer_file)`.

Comment: @letsc `os.path.abspath` simply turns a relative path into an absolute one relative to the current working directory (ex: `"foo.txt"` becomes `"/Users/username/foo.txt"` if I run python from my home directory on OSX). It will still only work if that path is a valid path, which in the general case probably isn't.